# Where does Daenerys keep her dragons?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire, dragons

I'm talking mainly about the TV series.

When the dragons were younger, she kept them in the cage most of the time (right?). Then they grew up a bit more, and they mostly stayed beside her. In the fourth season, we see that they are fairly grown (although not fully grown yet), they are not usually beside their mother, and they are more wild.

---

**Questions:**

- So when did Daenerys decide not to put them in the cage anymore? (At
  what age and size of the dragons?)
- In the fourth season, why don't we see the dragons that much?

**Related questions:** For example, when Daenerys reached Meereen, where are the dragons? Are they always flying freely and to further places? Do they come back to their mother whenever they want? Can Daenerys call them when they are far away? Do they sleep beside their mother?

**Note:** There might be more details in the book also.

Comment: This question reminded me of an old joke; Q. Where does Napoleon keep his armies? A. Up his sleevies

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Real World Answer

CGI at this level is *very* expensive. So rendering the dragons when they are not actively contributing to the plot would severely drain the budget. So we only ever see the dragons when we absolutely must. It's the same reason why we see so little of the Stark direwolves.

### TV Answer

We don't know. They certainly seem pretty big during season 4, and may or may not be caged anymore during Daenerys' march. We do see them uncaged and hunting in the first episode of season 4, but we don't know if they are caged again afterwards. However it seems from the latest episode (Season 4 Episode 6):

> That the dragons are now uncaged and are free to roam the land.

### Book Answer

During Daenerys' march they were always caged. However in the books they don't grow as fast as the in the TV show. Drogon, who is the largest, is described as being only as big as a dog during the attack on Astapor, so it's conceivable that they would still be caged.

But when Daenerys becomes queen of Meereen, the dragons are left to their own devices to hunt the countryside as they wish.

Answer (score 7):

The dragons are growing up and becoming more difficult to control. In last night's episode [The Laws of Gods and Men](http://www.hbo.com/#/game-of-thrones/episodes/4/36-the-laws-of-gods-and-men/synopsis.html) we see that her oldest dragon Drogon is:

> Roaming the countryside free and helping himself to a farmer's goats

This was hinted at earlier in the season, when her and Jorah watched the dragons fighting over a meal.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: @brain56 The short version is `Roaming the countryside free`. I believe that answers the question...

Comment: So I see. Please edit your answer to explicitly state this. :)

Comment: @brain56 - It already does, I copied this part from the spoiler tag...

Comment: Damn, I feel stupid for not realising that. I thought this was you just pointing out an observation and not stating it as an answer. Umm... Just edit something so I can withdraw my downvote. Sorry. :P

Comment: No problem, it's still Monday :)