# Why did Daenerys lock her dragons up and not interact with them at all?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I have not read the books. In the HBO presentation Daenerys incarcerates two of her dragons in some sort of dungeon. After evidently neglecting them, she is horrified at their size and anger when she visits them in Season 5 episode 1.

Her abandonment of the dragons until that point seemed out of character and irrational in regard to her aspirations. **Why didn't she spend time with them and play with them?**

The TV special seems to give no thought to their ever growing size and fierceness in terms of controlling them. It seems like the Dragon Mother is just hoping for the best without really being involved in some sort of training.

Comment: Related: [Why is Dany unable to control her dragon?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/126203/21267) and [Where does Daenerys keep her dragons?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/56150/21267)

Comment: @Mooz Where does Daenerys keep her dragons? Up her sleevies ... no, wait, wrong joke.

Comment: You mention you haven't read the books, but are you open to information from there?

Comment: Bad dragons!!!!

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple of scenes that played into that.  Obviously, the one where the shepherd comes in, and she assumes he wants compensation for a herd animal that was eaten or burned, but it's actually his small child, killed by Drogon.  She is, of course, utterly horrified and appalled.

Many times throughout the stories she is reminded that dragons are not pets, but wild, unpredictable and aggressive beasts.

There is a scene where she is with Drogon in the hills, and he's eating an animal he killed and when she tries to physically interact with him as she always does, he turns and snaps at her, very aggressively.

She fears she has lost control of them, and as they mature, they are not only getting more wild and aggressive, but their size and power is such that as they exert more will and aggression, she has no means to control them.

Going down to "play" with animals that are already being isolated because of their anger and aggression and raw power is something you might do with a pet, but not a dragon.  Chances are they would even be more enraged at being chained up and hidden away.

The same reason she puts them into isolation is the same reason she won't go down and interact, she fears that she can't control them any more.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that sounds all reasonable. So it seems that Daenrys took a great gamble in hatching the dragons, and that the HBO presentation didn't offer any of the misgivings and risks that Daenerys may have had throughout the story.